# Ruby map function in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby

I am really used to programming in Ruby. I am working in PHP now.

I have an array of objects, and I want to get all the ids of those objects and put them in an array.

In Ruby you would do:

```
my_arr.map { |arr| arr.id }
```

How would I do that in PHP? Do I need to do a foreach and push that id into an array?

Comment: http://php.net/array_map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php). For example:

```
$my_arr = array_map(function($el) { 
    return $el['id'];
}, $arr);
```